# Unable to Insert Into a Partitioned View

Tags: sql, view, partitioning

I have searched the web and many examples but cannot identify why I get this error:

> UNION ALL view 'devCascade_Gold1_hr.dbo.CustomAudit_View' is not
>   updatable because a partitioning column was not found.

I am creating a number of tables on the fly with a script that is designed to take a monstrous amount of data and shove it into a partitioned view to handle it better. For some reason I cannot insert data into the view and get the above error.

I have checked seemingly everything. Primary key - check, no identify columns - check. I insert into the table whos restraint I am testing fine, but not the view.

Here is how its all built up:

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @DataTabLabel as nvarchar(100), @sql as nvarchar(4000), @sqlView as nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @monthcount as tinyint, @filter as nvarchar(200), @droptext as nvarchar(80)
DECLARE @counter as int =1

DECLARE cur cursor for
select DISTINCT DataTabLabel from IntranetStdDataRequestCache
open cur
fetch next from cur into @DataTabLabel

IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.CustomAudit_View', 'V') IS NOT NULL
  DROP VIEW dbo. CustomAudit_View

SET @sqlView = 'CREATE VIEW CustomAudit_View AS
                SELECT * FROM CustomAudit'+CAST(@counter as nvarchar(3))
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    SET @filter = 'datatablabel = ''' + @DataTabLabel + ''''

    SET @droptext = 'DROP TABLE dbo.CustomAudit' + CAST(@counter as nvarchar(3))
    IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.CustomAudit'+CAST(@counter as nvarchar(3)), 'U') IS NOT NULL
        EXEC sp_executesql @droptext

    SET @sql = 'CREATE Table CustomAudit'+CAST(@counter as nvarchar(3)) +' (
          layoutid bigint ,
          displayemployeeid nvarchar (50) COLLATE database_default ,
          forename nvarchar (50) COLLATE database_default ,
          surname nvarchar (50) COLLATE database_default ,
          datatablabel nvarchar (50) COLLATE database_default 
          CONSTRAINT CK_CustomAudit'+CAST(@counter as nvarchar(3))+' CHECK ('+@filter+'),
          requesteddatetime datetime,
          username nvarchar (50) COLLATE database_default ,
          updatelevel nvarchar (20) COLLATE database_default ,
          updatetype nvarchar (20) COLLATE database_default ,
          field nvarchar (50) COLLATE database_default ,
          CurrentValue nvarchar (400) COLLATE database_default ,
          Value nvarchar (400) COLLATE database_default ,
          authorised nvarchar (20) COLLATE database_default ,
          authoriserdatetime datetime ,
          authemployeedesc nvarchar (100),
          recruitment bit
        CONSTRAINT PK_CustomAudit'+CAST(@counter as nvarchar(3))+' PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (displayemployeeid,datatablabel,requesteddatetime)
    )

    CREATE INDEX CustomAudit'+CAST(@counter as nvarchar(3))+'_AG ON CustomAudit'+CAST(@counter as nvarchar(3))+' (displayemployeeid, datatablabel) INCLUDE (field,requesteddatetime,username)
    CREATE INDEX CustomAudit'+CAST(@counter as nvarchar(3))+'_empid ON CustomAudit'+CAST(@counter as nvarchar(3))+' (displayemployeeid)
    CREATE INDEX CustomAudit'+CAST(@counter as nvarchar(3))+'_reqdate ON CustomAudit'+CAST(@counter as nvarchar(3))+' (requesteddatetime)'
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
    PRINT 'dbo.CustomAudit'+CAST(@counter as nvarchar(3))+' Created'
    PRINT 'Filter: ' + @filter

    IF @counter <> 1
    BEGIN
        SET @sqlView = @sqlView + ' UNION ALL 
               SELECT * FROM ' + 'CustomAudit'+CAST(@counter as nvarchar(3))
    END
    SET @counter = @counter + 1

fetch next from cur into @DataTabLabel
END

IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.CustomAudit_View', 'V') IS NOT NULL
  DROP VIEW dbo. CustomAudit_View


EXEC sp_executesql @sqlView
PRINT 'CustomAudit_View Created'

close cur
Deallocate cur
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

The tables generate fine - their individual checks work perfectly.
The view also generates and can be queried without issue - even the Execution plan shows it uses only the correct restrained tables when trying to get data back.
The person who provides the answer here wins my heart and soul.

I even tried removing the date fields and generating it all again just incase its the timestamp issue I keep seeing mentioned:

```
INSERT INTO CustomAudit_View
(layoutid , displayemployeeid, forename , surname , datatablabel,  username,
      updatelevel , updatetype, field , CurrentValue , Value, authorised ,  authemployeedesc,  recruitment)
      VALUES
      (83921,   33134,  'Postponement',' One'   ,'AUTO ENROLMENT',  'v',    'Direct','update'   ,'IsMemberOfQualifyingPensionScheme',
        0,  1   ,'N/A'  ,   'N/A',  0)
```

But nope - still it refuses to insert into the view. 
My table 60 is the only one with Auto Enrolement set as the constraint so now Im lost:

> CustomAudit60 datatablabel    ([datatablabel]='AUTO ENROLMENT')

Answer (score 0):

My soul is mine too keep this day.
You want to know the solution? Turns out my dynamic code was setting the same check constraint for more than 1 table:

```
DECLARE cur cursor for
select DISTINCT DataTabLabel from IntranetStdDataRequestCache a
UNION SELECT DISTINCT TabLabel FROM intranetpagesx
open cur
```

Now works!!!

A big thank you for this site for providing a comprehensive list of possibilities:
http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=54747